# interactive panel help in vb

Tags: java, vb.net, vb6

I need to program a form application for a university project. The application has a 2d array of panels that make up a grid that user can interact with. I have some experience with Java, so what I am trying to ask is if there is anyway to translate this line into Visual Basic:

```
pnl[x][y].addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
/**do stuff
**/};
```

Comment: Which event do you want to listen to? Mouse Click? Mouse Over? or What? :)

Comment: Click and move mostly. One more thing, the application I am making is part of a larger, pre-existing program that was written in vb6.

Comment: again, I am completely new to vb, so I do not know if there are any differences between vb6 and vb.net

Comment: Let me help. Which IDE do you use? Microsoft Visual Basic 6 or Visual Studio?

Comment: My plan is to write the code in 2010 so that I do not have to worry about build errors caused by some other part of the larger application. Once I have finished writing this program, my plan is to rewrite it in vb6.

Comment: Googled some stuff and I think I know how to go about this now. Thank you.

Comment: Urgh... that's like saying: I'll write the code in Java and then I'll later rewrite it in Pascal. I strongly suggest that you reconsider this plan. VB.NET and VB6 are completely different languages, especially when it comes to the UI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use control arrays, so you will only need one Click event shared among all form elements. http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-control-array-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which of the VB.NET UI libraries you are using, i.e., WinForms or WPF (what's the VB6 tag doing in your question, BTW?).

For example, to capture mouse moves in WinForms, you could do something like this:

```
AddHandler pnl(x)(y).MouseMove, AddressOf MyMouseMoveMethod
```

This attaches a handler function (see below) to the event that you want to handle.

```
Private Sub MyMouseMoveMethod(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    ... ''# The Mouse has been moved over the panel... do something
End Sub
```

The `MouseListener` thing in Java is an implementation of the *Observer pattern*. In .net, the same problems are solved through [events and event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx) instead. To find out which events are available and what signature is required for the event handler, check the MSDN documentation page of the Panel control you are using.

Comment: yeah...so the application that I am making is part of a larger application that is in vb6...probably should have mentioned that.